# Retornando rotas filhas em uma view abstrata no Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, angular-routes

Estou fazendo uma diretiva para criar um sistema de Wizzard, onde a navegação deste wizzard vai depender do número de rotas que se é definido em uma rota pai (abstract). Preciso saber se há alguma forma de quando eu iniciar um controller, eu trazer todas as rotas filhas existentes para aquela rota pai.

exemplo de rotas em um arquivo **routes.js**:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("app", {  url: "/",
    abstract : true,
    templateUrl: "templates/app.html",
    controller: "appController"
  })
  .state("app.foo", { url: "/foo",
    views: {
      'view-foo': {
        templateUrl: "views/foo.html",
        controller: "fooCtrl"
      }
    }    
  })
  .state("app.bar", { url: "/bar",
    views: {
      'view-foo': {
        templateUrl: "views/bar.html",
        controller: "barCtrl"
      }
    }    
  });
```

Na minha diretiva precisaria conseguir um resultado do tipo `["app.foo","app.bar"]` para que eu possa a partir disso trabalhar em funções do controller pai.

Alguém tem idéia de como fazer isso?